# jqplot : how can we set default value in bar chart

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am using this code to create my bar chart.

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot('fidtenuredivid', [line1], {
            title: '%%K_CATEGORY_VS_AMOUNT%%',
            animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
            seriesDefaults:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            pointLabels: { show: true,
                      stackedValue: true},
            color: "#00749F"
        },
            axes: {
              xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
              }
            }
          });
```

But i want it should show Black circle mark as default value for the each category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved.
[Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NEPk4/2/)

Please find below the sample code which does that, you can use this concept in your code.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var defaults = [
        ['2014-01-15 15:10:01', 15],
        ['2014-01-15 15:10:12', 10],
        ['2014-01-15 15:10:14', 5],
        ['2014-01-15 15:10:17', 19],
        ['2014-01-15 15:10:23', 15],
        ['2014-01-15 15:10:28', 12]
    ];

    var bars = [
        ['2014-01-15 15:10:01', 21],
        ['2014-01-15 15:10:12', 21],
        ['2014-01-15 15:10:14', 22],
        ['2014-01-15 15:10:17', 21],
        ['2014-01-15 15:10:23', 22],
        ['2014-01-15 15:10:28', 18]
    ];

    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [bars, defaults], {
        title: 'Default Date Axis',
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
            }
        },
        series: [{
            renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            pointLabels: {
                show: true,
                stackedValue: true
            },
            color: "#00749F",
            label: "peer expenses"
        }, {
            lineWidth: 1,
            showLine: false,
            markerOptions: {
                style: 'filledCircle',
                size: 40
            },
            label: "Expenses"
        }],
        legend: {
            show: true,
            location: 'e',
            placement: "outsideGrid"
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for your answer.Could you please tell me how to specify that circle mark is showing default value and bar is showing original value. like i have showed in diagram blue color shows 'peer expenses' and black color is showing your expenses.

Comment: i have edited my answer to include the legends. If you want to draw a circle inside legend then you have to draw legends by your self and not by jqplot.

Comment: Thanks a lot gyandeep. Could we get tooltip on circle also. Please let me know if it is possible.

Comment: Can we make it 3D also?

Comment: i dont think `jqplot` supports 3D.